# ¿como mantener el ID por donde iba al deserializar?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema. Estoy creando un periodico y cada noticia de este tiene una ID, yo voy craendo noticias y la id se crea autoincremental sola, hasta eso perfecto. Pero una vez salgo del proyecto y serializa, una vez lo cargo y deserializa al crear una noticia nueva la ID vuelve a empezar por 1 en vez de por donde la deje. OS dejo mi codigo

```
public class Noticias implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
private static int idAuto = 0;
private int id;
private String titulo;
private String sinopsis;
private String cuerpo;
private String autor;
private LocalDate fecha;
private boolean stado;
private List<String> p_clave;
private List<Integer> idRelacionado;

public Noticias(int id, String titulo, String sinopsis, String cuerpo, String autor, LocalDate fecha, boolean stado, List<String> p_clave, List<Integer> idRelacionado) {
    this.id = id;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
    this.cuerpo = cuerpo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.stado = stado;
    this.p_clave = p_clave;
    this.idRelacionado = idRelacionado;
}

public Noticias() {
    this.id = ++idAuto;
    this.titulo = "";
    this.sinopsis = "";
    this.cuerpo = "";
    this.autor = "";
    this.fecha = null;
    this.stado = false;
    this.p_clave = new ArrayList<>();
    this.idRelacionado = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static int getIdAuto() {
    return idAuto;
}

public static void setIdAuto(int idAuto) {
    Noticias.idAuto = idAuto;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getSinopsis() {
    return sinopsis;
}

public void setSinopsis(String sinopsis) {
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
}

public String getCuerpo() {
    return cuerpo;
}

public void setCuerpo(String cuerpo) {
    this.cuerpo = cuerpo;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public LocalDate getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(LocalDate fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public boolean isStado() {
    return stado;
}

public void setStado(boolean stado) {
    this.stado = stado;
}

public List<String> getP_clave() {
    return p_clave;
}

public void setP_clave(List<String> p_clave) {
    this.p_clave = p_clave;
}

public List<Integer> getIdRelacionado() {
    return idRelacionado;
}

public void setIdRelacionado(List<Integer> idRelacionado) {
    this.idRelacionado = idRelacionado;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nNoticias{" + "id=" + id + ", titulo=" + titulo + ", sinopsis=" + sinopsis + ", cuerpo=" + cuerpo + ", autor=" + autor + ", fecha=" + fecha + ", stado=" + stado + ", p_clave=" + p_clave + ", idRelacionado=" + idRelacionado + '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Periodico implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String nombre;
private List<Noticias> listaNoticias = new ArrayList();

public Periodico(List<Noticias> noticias) {
    this.listaNoticias = noticias;
}

public Periodico() {
    this.nombre = "la gaceta de PAtri";
    this.listaNoticias = listaNoticias = new ArrayList<>();

}

public List<Noticias> getListaNoticias() {
    return listaNoticias;
}

public void setListaNoticias(List<Noticias> listaNoticias) {
    this.listaNoticias = listaNoticias;
}

public void addNoticia(Noticias n) {
    listaNoticias.add(n);

}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String muestraNoticia() {
    String resultado = "";
    for (Noticias n : listaNoticias) {
        resultado += n.toString();
    }
    return resultado;
}

public List<Noticias> buscarNoticia(String autor) {
    List<Noticias> listanot = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaNoticias.size(); i++) {
        if (listaNoticias.get(i).getAutor().compareToIgnoreCase(autor) == 0) {

            listanot.add(listaNoticias.get(i));

        }

    }
    return listanot;

}

public Noticias buscarIdNoticia(int id) {
    for (Noticias p : listaNoticias) {
        if (p.getId() == id) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public int borrarNoticia(int id) {
    int borrado = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaNoticias.size(); i++) {

        if (listaNoticias.get(i).getId() == id) {

            listaNoticias.remove(i);

            borrado = 1;
        }

    }
    return borrado;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String mensaje = "" + getNombre() + "\n" + "Noticias: \n";
    for (Noticias n : listaNoticias) {
        mensaje += n.toString();
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Y en el main esta el serializa y deserializa que funciona perfectamente por ahorrar codigo no os voy aponer el main que no es necesario

Comment: Te refieres a que cada vez que paras y rearrancas tu programa empieza de cero? Si es eso, es normal porque inicializas la variable static a 0 y eso ocurre cada vez que arranca tu programa. Tendrías que implementar una manera de guardarte el último id al salir y cargarlo al iniciar. O al abrir tu programa, buscar primero la última noticia y iniciar el contador en uno más para la siguiente...

Comment: si es eso, y como hago eso?

Comment: Si estás usando Spring, puedes hacer que antes de pararse, guarde el valor en un archivo y cuando arranque, que lea ese fichero y construya las clases con ese valor.

Comment: Se me ocurre que lo guardes a nivel de Periodico, no de Noticia. Y sea Periodico el que se lo pasa a cada Noticia cuando crea una nueva. Al iniciar tu programa lees y cargas todas las noticias en el Periódico y la última te indica el valor para el próximo ID para la siguiente Noticia. Si al inicio no hay noticias previas de otra ejecución, lo inicias con cero.